# Bard API in Python for solving simple questions

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

```
from bardapi import Bard
import os

os.environ['_BARD_API_KEY']='api key'
input_text = "What is 1+1"
print(Bard().get_answer(input_text)['content'])`
```

It will result the answer of question 1+1 with the help of bard AI.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in the error its looking for the cookies which you haven't provided , Try the following workaround

```
import requests
from bardapi.constants import SESSION_HEADERS
from bardapi import Bard

token = "xxxxx"

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = SESSION_HEADERS
session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSID", token)
bard = Bard(token=token, session=session)
```

and then use :

```
bard.get_answer(input_text)['content']
```

hopefully it helps

Now on to the other part:

- Don't just attach the images of the errors (please mention it in the body itself)
- Elaborate your issue in the header because looking at yours it doesn't really mean anything and no one will have idea what are you trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the answer by stating the correct token:

```
from bardapi import Bard
import os

os.environ['_BARD_API_KEY']= token
input_text = "What is 1+1"
print(Bard().get_answer(input_text)['content'])
```

The token can be retrieved from the steps below:

1. Right click on https://bard.google.com/chat webpage
2. Select **inspect**.
3. Click on **Application** tab.
4. Select **Cookies**, followed by **https://accounts.google.com**
5. The **value** of **__Secure-1PSID** is the token required.

[image]